# Backtracking issue (I think?) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, backtracking

I like to challenge myself just for fun and I've come across to a problem which I just simply can not solve on my own. I've tried and tried, but I can not find a solution to it and that's why I came here to ask from you.

So let's assume we have three different arrays:

```
var y1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
var y2 = [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 ];
var y3 = [ 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30 ];
```

We also have five different integers:

```
var z1 = 200;
var z2 = 400;
var z3 = 600;
var z4 = 800;
var z5 = 1000;
```

How am I able to see the largest possible number, when the formula looks something like this:

```
x = z1*y1[0] + z2*y1[0] + z3*y2[0] + z4*y2[0] * z5*y3[0];
```

... and I only have 25 points to use to replace the zeros in the equation?

> For example:
>
> z1*y1[5] + z2*y1[5] + z3*y2[5] + z4*y2[5] * z5*y3[5] = 32000 (5+5+5+5+5 = 25)
>
> z1*y1[0] + z2*y1[10] + z3*y2[0] + z4*y2[10] * z5*y3[5] = 35000 (0+10+0+10+5 = 25)

I think I know how it should be done (backtracking?) but I just can't figure out how to o it exactly. I also couldn't find this type of a problem from the Internet, so if you know where to look that would be great as well because I'm not looking for a direct answer, I'd like to learn.

So any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You might want to work out how you'd solve the problem with paper and pencil first. There's not much about JavaScript that's particularly good or bad for a solution to this.

Comment: Since it's straightforward addition and multiplication, and the arrays are ascending, finding the largest possible number should be equal to 
`x = z1*y1[y1.length-1] + z2*y1[y1.length-1] + z3*y2[y2.length-1] + z4*y2[y2.length-1] * z5*y3[y3.length-1];`

**x = 480018000**

Comment: @Pointy I have tried to solve this, the reason why I'm doing it with Javascript is simply because I know it the best. I'm not looking for an answer to this particular situation, I'm trying to find a way to calculate this when there might be more variables or arrays and not the same numbers than presented in the example.

Comment: @holmberd That's not what I'm looking for. I know how to get the biggest number if you're allowed to use all you've got, but you're limited to 25 points like explained in the yellow box.

Comment: If you can't work out a process for doing the problem with pencil and paper, it really doesn't matter what programming language you choose. It's necessary to understand a problem and its solution before implementing the solution in code.

Comment: Ah I missed that little note. By assuming a ascending heuristic `max(25) = z1*y1[0] + z2*y1[0] + z3*y2[5] + z4*y2[10] * z5*y3[10]` Result: **480006000**

Comment: You can think of it as having five machines(m) that needs to perform one job(_n_), of varying processing times(_z_), and _y_ denote when to schedule each job. Finding the maximum makespan follows my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as having five machines(m) that needs to perform one job(n), of varying processing times(z), and y denote when to schedule each job.

Assuming a ascending heuristic:

```
max(25) = z1*y1[0] + z2*y1[0] + z3*y2[5] + z4*y2[10] * z5*y3[10] Result: 480006000
```